# I can't solve Tower of Hanoi on Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I know the algorithm :

```
(defun Hanoi (n) (if (= n 1) 1 (+ (* 2 Hanoi(- n 1)) 1)))
```

However, CLISP said

```
*** - IF: variable HANOI has no value
```

How could I tweak this? I can't find out the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Here is your code:

```
(defun Hanoi (n) 
  (if (= n 1)
      1
      (+ (* 2 Hanoi (- n 1))
         1)))
```

The error says:

```
*** - IF: variable HANOI has no value
```

So, inside the  `IF` you are making a reference to `HANOI` as a variable, and there is no such variable currently bound at this point. If we look closely, we can see the following expression:

```
(* 2 Hanoi (- n 1))
```

This expressions is the application of function `*` to 3 arguments, namely `2`, `Hanoi` and `(- n 1)`. The second argument, `Hanoi`, stands for a variable. But there is no such variable defined here (for example, with a `let`). You are supposed to call the funtion `#'Hanoi` using the same syntax as you did for multiplication or addition, which is: wrap the function's name in parentheses along with its arguments:

```
(hanoi (- n 1))
```

See https://common-lisp.net/documentation for resources about Common Lisp.

Answer (score 4):

You don't call functions as `f(x)` in Lisp, you call them as `(f x)`  So your recursive call to `hanoi` needs to be `(hanoi (- n 1))`.